# Rewrite Python Method Depending on Condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given these heavily simplified example methods:

```py
def get_latest_snapshot(db_arn):
    snapshots = source_rds_client.describe_db_snapshots(DBInstanceIdentifier=db_arn)['DBSnapshots']

def get_latest_cluster_snapshot(db_arn):
    snapshots = source_rds_client.describe_db_cluster_snapshots(DBClusterIdentifier=db_arn)['DBSnapshots']
```

I would like to end up with a single method that can handle either type of call; 'instance' or 'cluster'. As you can see, the only difference between the two is the addition of the word 'cluster' in the second method.

What I currently have is:

```py
def get_latest_snapshot(db_arn):
    try:
        snapshots = source_rds_client.describe_db_snapshots(DBInstanceIdentifier=db_arn)['DBSnapshots']
    except KeyError:
        snapshots = source_rds_client.describe_db_cluster_snapshots(DBClusterIdentifier=db_arn)['DBClusterSnapshots']
```

But I'd like to avoid this kind of hack, including if statements, for several reasons: Firstly, it relies on a specific exception which is not directly tied to what I'm looking to actually catch. Secondly it duplicates code, so doesn't actually solve the problem of two different methods for almost the same call.

The example above is heavily simplified, and my real usage involves many lines of duplication in many methods. They are all of same form, the addition of the word 'cluster' as above in the method name (as in `describe_db_cluster_snapshots` vs `describe_db_snapshots`), and the substitution of the word 'Instance' in the field (as in `DBClusterIdentifier` vs. `DBInstanceIdentifier`).

So I guess I'm after some way to rewrite the method depending on a condition (and passing in an extra argument such as `is_cluster` is acceptable to me), given those two known forms for the translation.

Comment: I think using a `is_cluster` flag is the best way if you cannot these two cases based on the `db_arn`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe create a list of possible attributes?

```
my_types = {
    'instance': (source_rds_client.describe_db_snapshots, DBInstanceIdentifier, DBSnapshots),
    'cluster': (source_rds_client.describe_db_cluster_snapshots, DBClusterIdentifier, DBClusterSnapshots)
}

def get_latset_snapshot(db_arn, db_type):
    method, keyword, dict_key = my_types[db_type]
    snapshot = method(**{keyword: db_arn})[dict_key]
```

And you can call it using `get_latest_snapshot(db_arn, 'cluster')`